# Need help repartitioning

Tags: partitioning, gnome-disk-utility

When I installed ubuntu, I gave it 30 gb think that I wasn’t going to use it much. Well, now I am short on space and I’d like to give it some more. I have a 50 gb chunk sitting **in front** of the partition that ubuntu is installed on, but I cannot figure out how to add it to the partition.

Comment: If it's unallocated space then simply boot a live session, run Gparted and resize (expand) the partition into the unallocated space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: I tried that, the free space is before the Ubuntu partition which is what my problem is, I am using gnome-disk-utility.

Comment: ChanganAuto Should I try using gparted instead?

Comment: You need to move the partition so the unallocated space is *after* it, like always.

Comment: I didnt see a way to do that in gnome disks

Comment: It's much harder to accomplish if the unallocated space is not immediately following. Can you provide a screenshot of your current partition layout?

Comment: I managed to do it with gparted, I couldn’t figure out how to do it with gnome-disk-utility. Thanks!

Comment: You gave no Ubuntu product details; but given the [recommend minimum disk size](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) for Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop & later is 25GB you were only 5GB above that which didn't allow for you adding many applications etc.